Cells on row will inherit the height of the cell with the biggest height (FLUTTER - Table Widget)
Context:
I am creating a Calendar display using the table widget in Flutter.
Problem: Each cells per row varies on height depending on the content of each cell. The problem is when rendered, the other cells on the row with no content does not inherit the height of the biggest cell. Tried all solutions I searched but either I can't make it work or it does not work.

  Widget tableContent() {
return SingleChildScrollView(
  physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  child: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
      Table(
        children: buildCalendar(),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);

}
List<TableRow> buildCalendar() {
List<TableRow> rows = [];

List<Widget> rowChildren = [];

for (int i = 0; i < startOffset; i++) {
  rowChildren.add(
    calendarTile(
      date: null,
      isLastInRow: false,
      isFirstInRow: i == 0,
      isLastRow: false,
    ),
  );
}

for (int day = 1; day <= daysInMonth; day++) {
  if (rowChildren.length == 7) {
    rows.add(TableRow(children: rowChildren));
    rowChildren = [];
  }

  rowChildren.add(
    calendarTile(
      date: DateTime(currentMonth.year, currentMonth.month, day),
      isLastInRow: rowChildren.length == 6,
      isFirstInRow: rowChildren.length == 0,
      isLastRow: (day + startOffset - 1) ~/ 7 ==
          (daysInMonth + startOffset - 1) ~/ 7,
    ),
  );
}

while (rowChildren.length < 7) {
  rowChildren.add(
    calendarTile(
      isLastInRow: rowChildren.length == 6,
      isFirstInRow: rowChildren.length == 0,
      isLastRow: (daysInMonth + startOffset - 1) ~/ 7 == rows.length,
    ),
  );
}

rows.add(TableRow(children: rowChildren));

while (rows.length < 5) {
  rows.add(
    TableRow(
      children: List.generate(
        7,
        (row) => Container(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

return rows;

}
